# Should I run haproxy for db and redis sentinel on web nodes?

Tags: redis, haproxy, high-availability, failover, sentinel

I am setting up a cluster of servers using vagrant and playing with Redis sentinel and HAProxy for Postgresql db connection (with pgpool). I was curious if it make sense to put haproxy and redis sentinel on each of my web server nodes and have them connect directly to those. The thought is that it can create a distributed connection to the DB and redis and reduce the single point of failure to having a single haproxy that they connect to and then split to different db nodes. I can also keep the database connect (via haproxy) and redis (via sentinel) encapsulated to the localhost. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

It only makes sense if you're trying to save up on resources/costs.

Please note that redis sentinel must have a finite list of sentinel instances, which doesn't fit the scenario of placing one per machine, as your maching count would probably scale/change.

Otherwise , it's always makes the most sense to put different infrastructure components ( especially those with clustering/HA nature, such as redis ) on different machines.

By mixing them all together, you usually end up with applications getting in the way of each other and stealing CPU from each-other once the load increases. You also risk designing your applications/scripts/flows to be location aware (i.e assume external resources are always local ) which is also not a really good practice.